# Choose correct answer from multiple answers using PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code for examining.

- I need to choose the correct answer and give grade for it.
- If the answer was wrong I need to tell the user that he had wrong answer. After that I need to send the grade to another table in my database.

Is there any way that you can hide your true answer because I already posted it  with my code to compare it with the answers.

```
<?php

function getQuestions()
{
    require("connection.php");
    $questions = array();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `question` order by id  ") or dir(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $questions['questions'] = $fetch;
        if (!empty($questions)) {
        echo "<table width='100%'>";
        foreach ($questions as $qstn)
            echo "<hr size='2%'>"; {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $qstn["question"] . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td><input type='radio'  name='ans1' required='required' title='Please Answer the Questions'>" . $qstn["ans1"] . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td><input type='radio' name='ans2' required='required' title='Please Answer the Questions'>" . $qstn["ans2"] . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td><input type='radio' name='ans3' required='required' title='Please Answer the Questions'>" . $qstn["ans3"] . "</td></tr>";
            "<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='TrueAns'>" . $qstn["TrueAns"] . "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        }
    }
    }
    return $questions;
}

getQuestions();

$submit  = $_POST['submit'];
$ans1    = $_POST['ans1'];
$ans2    = $_POST['ans2'];
$ans3    = $_POST['ans3'];
$TrueAns = $_POST['TrueAns'];
if ('ans1' == 'TrueAns') {
    echo "correct answer";
} else {
    echo "wrong answer";
}
if ('ans2' == 'TrueAns') {
    echo "correct answer";
} else {
    echo "wrong answer";
}
if ('ans3' == 'TrueAns') {
    echo "correct answer";
} else {
    echo "wrong answer";
}
?>
```

---

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="MOHAMMED" />
    <title>Question</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="test.php" method="POST">
      <button type="submit" value="answer">submit your answer</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Why are you storing the answer in the form? Instead of having the answer to validate against posted back to you, you should be getting the answer from the table after a post.

Instead of comparing your posted values to TrueAns, you want to get the ID back for the question, and compare it against $qstn[ "TrueAns" ] for that particular question.

The answer you validate against shouldn't ever need to be sent to the client, this can all be verified server side.